# limiting regex search range

Tags: search, regex

I have a long list of words, characters, and new lines, how do tell the regex to only search the text between TWO EXACT WORDS on the list?

This is what I came up with but it does NOT stop searching"

```
(?!color).*id":(.*?),\s.*name": "(.*?)",\s.*\s.*miles
```

example: I want the REGEX ton return the following and stop searching after it reaches the word color again.

Matches:

```
1159 SAM
1597 ROBERT
1423 CARLOS
```

**Code:**

I have a long list of words, characters, and new lines, how do tell the regex to only search the text between TWO EXACT WORDS on the list?

**Example:**

I want the REGEX to return the following and stop searching after it reaches the word color again.

Matches:

```
1159 SAM
1597 ROBERT
1423 CARLOS
```

Code:

```
{
"groups": [{
    "id": 113,
    "name": "CAPISCO",
    "color": "#07380f",
    "params": [{
        "id": 1559,
        "name": "SAM.",
            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"
}, {
        "id": 1597,
        "name": "ROBERT.",
            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"
}, {
        "id": 1423,
        "name": "CARLOS.",
            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"
"id": 113,
    "name": "CORBAEU",
    "color": "#09854",
 "id": 113,
    "name": "SALUD",
    "color": "#07380f",
        "id": 1012,
}, {


            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"
}, {
        "id": 98,
        "name": "ANNIE.",
            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"
}, {
        "id": 1367,
        "name": "PETE.",
            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"

        "id": 866,
        "name": "Jay.",
            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"
}, {
        "id": 15933,
        "name": "JEAN.",
            "km": "1500",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "900",
            "miles": "0"
        }, {
            "km": "320",
            "miles": "0"
```

Comment: The formatting and length of this question are going to make most users give it a -1 or try to close it. Please edit and clean up the question.

Comment: SORRY! I don't know how to format my code!!!

Comment: There are buttons over the editor window, use them.

Comment: I have cleaned up your post some. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a pattern matching language. With it, you only define a pattern.
There are no means of keeping a counter to remember the number of matches - that is solely up to the implementation using the regex engine - for instance you can write a bit of code in any regex-supporting programming language to keep count of your matches and stop after *n* matches have been found.
You can only construct a regex that will match a given group exactly a predefined number of times by means pattern repetition. In other words - repeat your pattern three times, to get three matches. For example:

- Base pattern for match: `(expr)`
- Pattern for one match between boundary words: `boundaryword(?:.*?\s)+?(expr)(?:.*?\s)+?boundaryword`
- Pattern for two matches between boundary words: `boundaryword(?:.*?\s)+?(expr)(?:.*?\s)+?(expr)(?:.*?\s)+?boundaryword`
- Pattern for threematches between boundary words: `boundaryword(?:.*?\s)+?(expr)(?:.*?\s)+?(expr)(?:.*?\s)+?(expr)(?:.*?\s)+?boundaryword`

et cetera... In your case 'boundaryword' is 'color'.

There is no way with regex to tell it to find an unknown number of matches and then stop at a given word. Typical regex methods either find just the first match, or all pattern matches in a document. Your problem requires a custom implementation. In a programming language you could write a loop that first matches boundaryword's position, from there matches your pattern, and keeps matching that pattern to find consecutive elements until it approaches the next boundaryword, where it stops.